# Unknown column lat in sql query

Tags: sql

I'm running below query and it is giving error. I have tried many solutions, but no output. Please help me out. It works perfectly fine in select statement but not in the having clause.

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, ROUND((3959 * acos(cos(radians(1)) * cos(radians(location.lat)) * cos(radians(location.lng) - radians(1)) + sin(radians(1)) * sin(radians(location.lat)))), 2) as distance
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `location` ON `users`.`id` = `location`.`user_id`
WHERE `users`.`id` <> 7

SELECT `users`.`id`
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `location` ON `users`.`id` = `location`.`user_id`
WHERE `users`.`id` <> 7 
HAVING ROUND((3959 * acos(cos(radians(1)) * cos(radians(location.lat)) * cos(radians(location.lng) - radians(1)) + sin(radians(1)) * sin(radians(location.lat)))), 2) <= 1000
```

Comment: You may get help from - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236125/unknown-aggregate-column-in-having-clause

Comment: I don't know what platform this is but `having` makes no sense without `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer : [Unknown column in 'having clause'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105812/unknown-column-in-having-clause). You have to specify `location.lat` and  `location.lng` in the select clause.

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, location.lat, location.lng 
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `location` ON `users`.`id` = `location`.`user_id`
WHERE `users`.`id` <> 7 
HAVING ROUND((3959 * acos(cos(radians(1)) * cos(radians(location.lat)) * cos(radians(location.lng) - radians(1)) + sin(radians(1)) * sin(radians(location.lat)))), 2) <= 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to wrap  `ROUND((3959 * acos(cos(radians(1)) *..., 2)` within an aggregation such as

`having avg( ROUND((3959 * acos(cos(radians(1)) *..., 2) ) <= 1000` or

`having sum( ROUND((3959 * acos(cos(radians(1)) *..., 2) ) <= 1000` .. etc.

and you need to add `group by users.id` before `having` clause.

non-aggregated columns or calculated columns cannot be included within a having clause.